# Introducing delay between messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I use Node.js. I have an MQTT message event handler
`index.js`

```
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // calls another function
  my_function(topic,message);
})
```

which calls another function `my_function` on receiving messages.

```
async function my_function(topic,message) {
   const value = await dataFromPLC();
///processes the value together with message
}
```

The function `dataFromPLC` exported from another file using `exports.dataFromPLC = dataFromPLC` and imported into my main function looks like this
`PLCfunctions.js`

```
let client = new S7Client(plcSettings);
client.on('error', console.error);
 
async function dataFromPLC (){
  try {
    await client.connect();
  } catch (err){
    console.error(err);
  }
 
  try {
    // Read DB
    const res = await client.readDB(dbNr, dbVars);
    return res;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    client.disconnect();
  }
}
```

There is no issue when I receive a single MQTT message or there is sufficient delay between messages. However when I receive two MQTT messages, both of them calls `my_function` and subsequently `dataFromPLC` without much delay in between. I receive an error as there is not sufficient time for the PLC connection to close before the second message tries to use the connection again. I have looked at different options and am not quite sure about how to solve the problem. Can I get some help please?

Comment: Are you connecting to, and disconnecting from your database every single time a message comes? Is that a good practice? I always open one connection at start, and that's it. One time `await client.connect()` at the very beginning of the script, job done. It takes a few seconds but it's only once.

Comment: I should have been more clear. It is connection to Siemens S7 PLC over TCP/IP. Since I dont receive MQTT messages often (not more than 10 in a day), I thought it wasteful to keep the PLC connection open. Also I'm not quite sure if it would automatically reconnect when the PLC is switched off in the evening and started the next day. So I thought this was a safe way. And would it solve the problem of the next function call trying to read data from PLC before the first is done?

Comment: Aaaah indeed, this is completely different from what I thought. I don't even now what's a Siemens S7 PLC :)

Comment: You need all messages or just messages every x amount of time? if you need the messages for example like 200ms you can debounce the message handler and just ignore some events in between, so you can get at least 1 message every 200 ms constantly (this applies to sending or receiving), look for `debounce`, that's a useful concept in this context.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastián Espinosa. But all messages are unique and I need to record all of them. These messages are generated just on change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to set up a queue of messages, so that `onMessage` only places the input in the queue and defers its processing until later on. For example, you could make the queue a Promise with `then` as enqueue operation. This way it's guaranteed that no processing starts until all previous ones are completed.

Here's a small demo, a click on the button simulates an incoming message:

```js
let QUEUE = Promise.resolve()

function onMessage(msg) {
    console.log('GOT MESSAGE', msg)
    QUEUE = QUEUE.then(() => process(msg))
}

let pause = n => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, n));

async function process(msg) {
    console.log('BEGIN', msg)
    await pause(200); console.log('busy', msg)
    await pause(200); console.log('busy', msg)
    await pause(200); console.log('busy', msg)
    await pause(200); console.log('busy', msg)
    await pause(200); console.log('busy', msg)
    console.log('END', msg)
}

msg = 0
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => onMessage(++msg))
```

```html
<button>message</button>
```

Comment: Thanks gerog. I tried your suggestion. It does not seem to work. I updated my question

Comment: Your answer was correct. Thanks @georg. It was a stupid mistake of declaring one of my variables without a `let` in the function. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: @SinuSen if the answer is correct, don't forget to select it as the answer as well - it helps future readers as well